How to Run Multiple Instances of a Class Concurrently in a Single Python Application Using Asyncio?
I'm trying to run multiple instances of a class concurrently in a single Python application, simulating the effect of having separate terminals running each class independently. My goal is to have each instance operate independently and not block each other. I'm using asyncio for concurrency.
Edit: They technically i think they do run congruently but the awaits in one instance of an operations class will cause all of the other operations class to await that too.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:
import os
from operations import Operations  # Assuming this is my custom class

# Load environment variables
os.environ['ADDRESS1'] = 'address1'
os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY1'] = 'private_key1'
os.environ['ADDRESS2'] = 'address2'
os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY2'] = 'private_key2'

class Operations:
    def __init__(self, address, private_key):
        self.address = address
        self.private_key = private_key

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            print(f"Running operations for {self.address}")
            await do_other_thing()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

# Initialize instances with different addresses and private keys
instances = [
    Operations(os.getenv('ADDRESS1'), os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY1')),
    Operations(os.getenv('ADDRESS2'), os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY2'))
]

async def run_instance(instance):
    await instance.run()

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(run_instance(instance)) for instance in instances]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

The Problem:
Even though I'm using asyncio.create_task to run each instance concurrently, it seems like the await calls within each Operations instance are causing delays, making it appear as if they are not running completely independently.
What I Tried:
Ensuring that each operation within the run method uses await properly to allow other tasks to run concurrently.
Adding small sleep delays to prevent busy looping.
What I Need:
I need guidance on how to effectively run multiple instances of a class concurrently in a single Python application, ensuring they operate independently and maximize concurrency. Essentially, I want each Operations instance to behave as if it's running in a separate terminal.
Additional Information:
Python version: 3.12
Using asyncio
How can I achieve truly independent and concurrent execution of these class instances? Any help or pointers to best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Your example isn't self-contained enough to show any actual problem. (What does do_other_thing() do? Why is Operations imported and defined? Did you verify that your issue occurs with the code you're showing us?)


I'm using asyncio for concurrency.

That may be, but just "using asyncio" doesn't make all of your code magically asynchronous. I think your actual code (not the paraphrased stuff you're showing us) is actually mostly blocking, if you're seeing blocking behavior.

Essentially, I want each Operations instance to behave as if it's running in a separate terminal.
How can I achieve truly independent and concurrent execution of these class instances?

Truly independent and concurrent? Have a single script do the work for a single address/private key and then spawn multiple processes.
processes = []
for address, private_key in [
    ("foo", "bar"),
    ("baz", "quux"),
]:
    processes.append(
        subprocess.Popen(
            [sys.executable, "my_operations_script.py"],
            env={
                **os.environ,
                "ADDRESS": address,
                "PRIVATE_KEY": private_key,
            },
        )
    )

for process in processes:
    process.wait()

